# Чем put отличается от patch?

Tags: javascript, http, api, rest, put

Изучаю REST API. Не понимаю отличия метода PUT от PATCH: они же оба используются для обновления данных... Статьи в интернете на русском предоставляют много воды, нет ли ответа четко по-сути вопроса?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отладка JS в react-приложениях, использующих REST](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163858/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-js-%d0%b2-react-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-rest)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ответ по сути вопроса можно найти [тут](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/). **PUT** требует полного дублирования всех полей объекта вместе c измененным: непродублированные поля будут затерты. Этот метод ведет себя как присваивание. Ниже я привел разбор полетов программы [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server).

До запроса PUT *http://localhost/cars*:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Mazda", "year": "01.01.2001"}
```

Содержимое запроса PUT *http://localhost/cars/1*:

```
{"year": "02.02.2010"}
```

После запроса PUT *http://localhost/cars*:

```
{"id": 1, "year": "02.02.2010"}
```

**PATCH** же предоставляет возможность отправить несколько полей, будет произведено слияние по аналогии с [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

До запроса PATCH *http://localhost/cars*:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Mazda", "year": "01.01.2001"}
```

Содержимое запроса PATCH *http://localhost/cars/1*:

```
{"year": "02.02.2010"}
```

После запроса PATCH *http://localhost/cars*:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Mazda","year": "02.02.2010"}
```