# Разница (отличия) между PUT и PATCH в REST

Tags: api, rest

В чём отличия между этими методами? Оба производят обновления объектов.

Comment: Кажется, дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1057964/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-put-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-patch?rq=1

Comment: Почему поставили дубликат в эту сторону? Связь должна быть обратной @MikhailIonkin

Comment: ставил не я. А вообще, это логично, т.к. тот вопрос был раньше

Comment: @MikhailIonkin https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11753/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: Это противоречит правилам и не логично

Comment: если ты посмотришь историю действий по вопросу, то заметишь, что закрыл вопрос @Grundy. собственно, к нему и можно обратиться. К нему или к другому модератору

Comment: @MikhailIonkin спасибо

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`PATCH` используется для частичного изменения ресурса. `PUT` создает новый ресурс или заменяет представление целевого ресурса, данными представленными в теле запроса.

Иными словами, в `PATCH` вложенный объект содержит набор инструкций, описывающих, как ресурс, находящийся в данный момент на исходном сервере, должен быть модифицирован для создания новой версии. А в `PUT` содержится новая версия ресурса целиком.

В отличие от `PUT`, `PATCH` не идемпотентный, это подразумевает что успешные идентичные `PATCH` запросы могут иметь отличные эффекты. Однако, возможно выдавать запросы `PATCH` таким образом, чтобы они были идемпотентные.

```
+----------------------------+-----+-------+
|                            | PUT | PATCH |
+----------------------------+-----+-------+
| Запрос имеет тело          | Да  | Да    |
| Успешный ответ имеет тело  | Нет | Да    |
| Меняет состояние сервера   | Да  | Да    |
| Идемпотентный              | Да  | Нет   |
| Кэшируемый                 | Нет | Нет   |
| Допускается в HTML-формах  | Нет | Нет   |
+----------------------------+-----+-------+
```

Спецификации методов на английском: [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)

По данному вопросу хорошая документация есть на [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

**UPDATE**

`PATCH` не является [идемпотентным](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Idempotent) (одноитоговым, т.е. повторный запрос не меняет состояние сервера и приводит к тому же результату), т.к. в него можно вставить инструкцию добавления элемента. Тогда повторный запрос добавит его еще раз. А вот `PUT` просто перезаписал бы ресурс целиком (снова), т.е повторный запрос не приводит к разным результатам. Другие примеры: `GET` запрос идемпотентный: сколько бы раз ты не запрашивал в Google некоторый запрос, Google вернет тебе тот же результат. `POST` не идемпотентный: он может вставлять в базу новую строку каждый раз.

Comment: Как по-русски будет "идемпотентный"?

Comment: @edem повторный запрос приводит к другому результату

Comment: Почему для PATCH значение "Нет" в таблице?

Comment: @edem поправил коммент. Т.е. GET запрос, например, идемпотентен: сколько бы раз ты не запрашивал в гугл некоторый запрос, гугл вернет тебе тот же результат. А вот POST запрос не идемпотентный: он модет вставлять в базу новую строку каждый раз

Comment: @edem PATCH is neither safe nor idempotent as defined by [RFC2616], Section 9.1. [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789)
Например, в PATCH можно вставить инструкцию добавления элемента. Тогда повторный запрос добавит его еще раз. А вот PUT просто перезаписал бы ресурс целиком (снова)

Comment: Прекрасное пояснение. Добавьте его в вопрос. Такие слова ясности не прибавят читающим ибо.

Answer (score 43):

Представьте, что у вас на сайте публикуются статьи. У статей есть заголовок и содержание, которые вы можете редактировать.

```
PUT /articles/12

{
  title: 'Новый заголовок',
  content: 'Новое содержание'
}
```

```
PATCH /articles/12

{
  title: 'Новый заголовок',
  content: 'Новое содержание'
}
```

Они работают идентично. Отличия возникают, если вы изменяете например *только заголовок*.

```
PUT /articles/12

{
  title: 'Новый заголовок'
}
```

```
PATCH /articles/12

{
  title: 'Новый заголовок'
}
```

Первый запрос изменит заголовок `title` и очистит поле `content`, потому что вы его не передали. `PUT` меняет объект целиком.

Второй запрос изменит только поле заголовок, не трогая поля `content`, потому что вы его не передали. `PATCH` изменяет отдельные поля ресурса.

Answer (score 7):

`PUT` - обновление объекта целиком, `PATCH` - обновление поля объекта, можно и методом `PUT` обновить одно поле, однако метод `PUT` будет **проходить все поля** объекта и искать необходимое, в отличии от `PATCH`, который **не обходит объект** целиком.

Более подробно по [ссылке](https://rapidapi.com/blog/put-vs-patch/) (англ.)