# Отладка JS в react-приложениях, использующих REST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, rest, cors

Уважаемые господа,
есть вопрос, связанный с отладкой js при использовании react.

История равивалась так:

1. Сначала я разработал простое SPA приложение в стиле "тонкий клиент": просто веб -страница, на которой работает js-код.
   Это код вызывает REST методы на сервере и отображает данные.

Сервер, который реализует всю эту функциональность - простой код (на С++, запускается на порту 9000), который умеет

- отдавать статические файлы
- отвечать на REST - запросы клиента

2. Теперь я переписываю клиентское приложение на react. Сервер я хочу оставить без изменений!

Для этого я взял тот шаблон, который называется в руководствах по реакту Create React App.

После команды
`npx create-react-app my-app`
я получил папку, в которой есть подпапки node_modules, public, src, а также несколько файлов.

После запуска приложения

```
    cd my-app
    npm start
```

мой браузер заходит на страницу http://localhost:3000/ .

Самое приятное в этом процессе - что если я меняю код компонентов, находящихся в папке src, то в барузере автоматически рефрешится страница, и отображаются изменения, которые я внёс.

Но есть проблема. Для того, чтобы этот процесс происходил, надо, чтобы работал сервер node.js на 3000-м порту.

А чтобы я мог из react - приложения вызывать rest - методы своего сервера, он должен быть запущен, и код, работающий в браузере, должен быть загружен с моего сервера.

При попытке отлаживаться с запущенной node.js ни одно обращение к моему серверу не произойдет: происходит ошибка CORS policy (см. [image: картинку])

Я могу обойти эту проблему так:

я запускаю команду `npm run build`, в результате в react-проекте создаётся папка build.

Потом я перекладываю её содержимое в ту папку моего собственного сервера, из которой происходит раздача статиеских файлов.

Тогда - "всё работает", то есть, по крайней мере, обращение к моему серверу на блокируются CORS policy.
Но это сильно усложняет отладку: при внесении малейшего изменения в код на js нужно пересобрать приложение, переложить его и отрефрешить страницу в браузере. Причем js - код там уже "упакован", то есть, при возникновении ошибки в браузере номер строки с ошибкой не соответсвует стоке исходного кода (ведь именно в этой "упаковке" и заключается сборка react - приложений)

Я думаю, что есть какой то более правильный способ отладки REST - приложений, написанных на реакте.
Но я этого способа не знаю. Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, как делать такую отладку?

Дополнение.

По совету, который мне дали в комментариях, я дописал в вызов вот такой код:

```
    devTool = ()=>{
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*';
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'origin, content-type, accept'; 
        // // let config = {
        //   headers: {
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, content-type, accept'
        //   }
        // }
        let data = { "req_type": 3}
        axios.post('http://charts.eurotest-online.ru/api/Techreglaments/', data)
    }
```

К сожалению, это не помогло - я по прежнему получаю ошибку CORS:
[image: ошибка CORS]

У меня впечатление, что это просто какая то проблема с синтаксисом. Не могли бы Вы глянуть опытным взглядом, что я делаю не так?
Спасибо!

**Дополнение номер два**.

Большое спасибо Вам за подсказки.

Я хотел сделать изящное решение, не использующее промежуточный прокси.

Сделал еще один "подход к снаряду".

Итак, у меня два серера: node 'для реакта' на порту 3000 и REST - сервер на порту 9000. Оба на localhost.

Мне @Alex Krass любезно подсказал, что HTTP header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' должен посылаться со стороны сервера, отвечающего на REST - запросы.

Отлично.

Я добавил в заголовки http-ответа ВСЕ разрешения, котрые нагуглил:

```
    resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

Проверил постменом.

Постман заголовки в ответе сервера видит:

[image: ответ сервера]

Но.

К сожалению, проклятая ошибка

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/api/Techreglaments/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

осталась на месте.

Причем, на REST - сервер при запросе со стороны браузера приходит запрос типа OPTIONS. А когда я тестирую постменом - всё хорошо, приходит POST - запрос.

Я просто уже не знаю, что думать.

Привожу текст ошибки в виде картинки:

[image: CORS error in details]

Если Вы сможете увидеть в ней что то, что я пропустил - напишите, пожалуйста.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Если это ваш собственный REST сервер, то правильным способом будет при отладке разрешить ему отдавать данные через передачу правильных заголовков `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Поскольку это браузер, не получаю нужный HEADER, блокирует запрос. В противном случае придется извращаться и делать какие-либо промежуточные тестовые примеры.

Comment: @AlexKrass, я попробовал дописать нужные заголовки со стороны node. Что то пошло не так... не могли бы Вы еще раз глянуть? я дописал результат в первоначальный вопрос

Comment: @S.H. ваша проблема заключается в том, что сервер отдает заголовки в которых не разрешает кросс доменные запросы. Для решение этой проблемы необходимо прописать глобально заголовки в самом сервере. Подробнее можно прочитать в этой статье - [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611)

Comment: @S.H. я так понял у вас проблема не в node, а еще дальше в REST сервисе 192.168.1.68:9000, который `простой код (на С++, запускается на порту 9000)`. Заголовки должны возвращаться с его стороны.

Comment: Можно еще попробовать всякие прокси, как и писали в ответе или посмотреть тут: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/ Хотя конфигурировать подобное мне еще не приходилось.

Comment: @AlexKrass, всё сделал, как мне кажется, в лучшем виде. Но - пока не помогло. Вся диагностика и описаниеи - дописаны к вопросу. Если Вам не лень - гляньте еще раз, может, увидите, где именно я ошибаюсь? Спасибо.

Comment: @S.H. браузер может послать OPTIONS, это правда, на него тоже нужно ответить с заголовками `Access-Control-Allow-*`, без контента и статусом 204. Цикл общения можно посмотреть в [ресурсах mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), там хорошие диаграммы взаимодействия со списком ответов. Чтобы было проще, можно смотреть содержание запросов в консоли браузера на вкладке `Network`, там же сразу можно посмотреть на заголовки `Headers`, которые вернул сервер. Еще можно попробовать это провернуть изначально без React, просто из консоли через JS стандартный fetch.

Comment: Ну и еще есть `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"` в ответ, тоже может быть важен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У webpack должна быть возможность проксировать запросы через его сервер:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Или можно поднять haproxy перед обоими:
`/usr/sbin/haproxy -f my_haproxy.cfg`

```
defaults
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client  900s
  timeout server  900s
frontend fe_http
  mode http
  bind :1080 
  acl a_api path_beg /api/
  use_backend be_api if a_api
  default_backend be_http
backend be_http
  mode http
  server se_http 127.0.0.1:3000
backend be_api
  mode http
  server se_http 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: Очень хорошее предложение. Спасибо. В принципе, надо всё, что без префикса /api/ пропускать на ноду (localhost, порт 3000), а всё, что с префиксом /api/ - на localhost, порт 9000. Если конфиг попадётся - было бы интересно.

Comment: добавил конфиг haproxy

Comment: Спасибо, круто, до сих пор я имел дело только с nginx, как раз интересно его сравнить с haproxy