# Fetch кроссдоменный запрос (c авторизацией) для получения html

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, cors, csrf

Как я могу запрашивать страницы с другого домена, если там есть авторизация?

Приложение на React запрашивает старницы с другого домена.
Другой домен - это django-сервер. Я могу получить страницу авторизации GET запросом, отренднрить её в реакте и войти. Но так я ухожу со своего React приложения.

На django предусмотрена страница авторизации без проверки csrf_token - так я могу пройти авторизацию, используя fetch().

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_without_csrf", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  credentials: "include",
  body: new String(`name=***&password=***`),
}).then((res) => {
  ...
})
```

Но После того, как я отправляю запрос на другую страницу - сервер отдаёт мне снова страницу авторизации.

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
    },
    credentials: "include",
  })
    .then((res) => {
      ...
    })
```

Я понимаю, что для проверки сервер использует csrf_token, но не понимаю, как он отдаётся. document.cookie возвращает мне токен, когда я делаю запрос авторизациию. credentials: "include" разрешает мне передавать cookie.

Вопрос такой, могу ли я вообще с помощью запросов отрисовывать у себя запрашиваемые у сервера элементы? И, если могу, где я что упускаю?

Comment: А бек у вас есть? Так вот если есть то ваш бек может хранить у себя многое и общятся со многими если вам тяжело с фронта это контролировать

Comment: @AzizUmarov Я понимаю. Но переписывать бэк очень не хочется. А если быть точным, то это не в моей компетенции. Я пока переписываю django, с которым не работал вообще - угроблю работающий сайт. Я по максимуму хочу уйти в реакт. Но если это вот точно невозможно - конечно буду с бэком работать.

Comment: Рендерить html страницы через реакт, это совсем не "уйти в реакт", как Вы сказали.

Comment: А если по существу, то скорее всего бэк устанавливает сессию, и соответственно что то устанавливается в куку. И если эта установленная кука не может ходить по разным доменам, или на бэке настроен cors, то вряд-ли что то получится. Но я могу ошибаться

Comment: Переписывание и создание дополнительно одного роута думаю это разные задачи. Я не предлагаю переписывать я предлагаю проксировать запросы через свой бек

Comment: поднять haproxy перед обоими серверами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164056/395779