# Fetch - запрос к другому сайту

Tags: javascript

Может вопрос аналогичен и есть уже другие, но я немного не разобрался. Как я слышал — fetch не может делать запросы на другие сайты или на порт. Вроде как надо указать какие-то заголовки специальные. Это так? Или если не так, то как сделать запрос к другому сайту?

`var api = fetch("http://example.com:4540");`

Есть собственный сайт, где нужно сделать запрос по порту.

Comment: Может. У вас с cors наверное проблемы? Покажите код

Comment: Вопрос отредактировал.

Comment: поднять haproxy перед обоими серверами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164056/395779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есди кратко, то:

`fetch` без проблем делает запрос на другие домены, так же, как и на свои родные.
только для кросс-доменных запросов есть дополнительная процедура, а именно:

- перед запросов (допустим, `POST`), браузер делает **предзапрос** (**preflight**) на сервер в виде запроса с методом `OPTIONS`
- в каждом запросе браузер автоматически вставляет в запрос заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, в который записывает Вам домен, например: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://lolo.com`. сервер же, в свою очередь, смотрит на этот заголовок и решает, обрабатывать ли Ваш запрос, или нет.
- если он согласен, то отправляет ответ со статусом **200**, браузер его принимает и **только после этого** он оправляет Вас главный запрос, который Вы указали в Вашем `fetch`.
- если же сервер несогласен принимать Ваши запросы, то он *отвергнет* Ваш запрос и Вы получите ошибку в консоли.

---

собственно, более красиво и подробно [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-crossorigin)

---

**UPDATE** по вопросу в комментарии

если хотите указать Вашему `Express` серверу, чтобы он принимал любые кросс-доменные запросы, то вот **одно из** решений:

```
// это всё код middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // разрешает принимать запросы со всех доменов
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'); // какие методы в запросах разрешается принимать
    next();
});
```

Comment: А если у меня сервер на Node.js, то там такие запросы будет пропускать?

Comment: ну смотря как сервер настроен) по умолчанию не должен. могу Вам в ответе написать решение для `NodeJS` сервера

Comment: Давайте, буду благодарен.