# Почему немогу взять данные со своего localhost .?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend

Есть свой localhost по адресу localhost:8000/ping

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему то с него не могу взять данные а с другово api адреса получается. То есть дела не в моём коде . Использую linux и браузер Ghrome.
Вот код

```
    class Judges extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mypersons : null
    };
  }
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/ping`, {
       headers: {  // погуглил и все предлогают использовать такое решение но оно мне не помогает
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
          'crossorigin':true
  }) 
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)  // ничего не выводит 
      const persons = res.data;
     this.setState({ persons : persons });
     })
  }
 render() {
    return (
      <div >
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
          <div>
            {this.state.mypersons}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Judges;
```

В консоли выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в коде указана схема http, а в ошибке почему-то упоминается https. И не очевидно, по какому протоколу отрыта текущая страница. Включите полное отображение URL в строке адреса.

Comment: @mymedia не ту картинку с ошибкой загрузил всё свой вопрос поправил

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163858/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-js-%D0%B2-react-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в вашем бекенде. Вы должны добавить [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) в ответе сервера. И раз уже используете then не мешало бы использовать и catch тоже. В [Википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) тоже есть дохотчевая схема работы CORS.

Comment: ... и я хотел бы по горячим следам добавить, что недавно задавал подобнный вопрос: javascript - Отладка JS в react-приложениях, использующих REST - Stack Overflow на русском
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163858/Отладка-js-в-react-приложениях-использующих-rest

Comment: Да вопросы с CORS  выходят регулярно